# Where to download the source code of android.widget.Gallery?

Tags: android, android-source

I need to customize the `android.widget.Gallery`. Where can I download the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/Gallery.java

I like GrepCode most because it's really convenience to browser Android source code online, as well as reference others class.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the link to the latest version of the `android.widget` package:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/

You can find the source to `Gallery.java` there. Of 
course you can also check out the whole source code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of Git repos: https://android.googlesource.com

It's a good idea to check this guide out: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

And here is the actual class:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java)

In linux or mac you may download the whole source. [see here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java&q=android.widget.Gallery&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc)

[Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) is such an underused resource. Enjoy it.

You will likely need other files from the source code as well.
Also, make sure to document the changes you make or you will face a hell of a challenge when you want to update to a new version of the Gallery.

Comment: Google Code search is no longer working now